# Why can I build but not publish my .net webapp in visual studio 2015? I could publish yesterday

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

Up until yesterday I could publish my .net web app.

But I started getting the error : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : Access is denied

Here is the log for the compile and publishactivity, compile works file.
I can run the web app when I click on 'IIS Express' in Visual Studio 2015 but I can't publish it.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: [MyProjectName], Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\gitRepository\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]" --configuration Release --no-dependencies
1>  Project [MyProjectName] (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
1>  Compiling [MyProjectName] for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1
1>  Removing read-only attributes in C:\gitRepository\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\bin\
1>  Removing read-only attributes in C:\gitRepository\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\..\packages\
1>  copying resources to DEBUG
1>  0 File(s) copied
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Invalid path
1>  copying resources to RELEASE
1>  0 File(s) copied
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Invalid path
1>  Compilation succeeded.
1>      0 Warning(s)
1>      0 Error(s)
1>  Time elapsed 00:00:03.7134777
1>   (The compilation time can be improved. Run "dotnet build --build-profile" for more information)
2>------ Publish started: Project: [MyProjectName], Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to C:\gitRepository\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\.\bin\Release\PublishOutput...
Environment variables:
Path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs;.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish "C:\gitRepository\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]\[MyProjectName]" --framework net461 --output "C:\Users\[myuser]\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\[MyProjectName]106" --configuration Release --no-build
Publishing [MyProjectName] for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1/win7-x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : Access is denied

2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have 2 errors in the error tab

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error       Access is denied    [MyProjectName]     0   

Error       Invalid path    [MyProjectName] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262
```

the line 262 of the 'Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Target file is

```
<Dnx
      RuntimeExe="$(SDKToolingExe)"
      Condition="'$(_DesignTimeHostBuild)' != 'true'"
      ProjectFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
      Arguments="$(_BuildArguments)"
      />
```

What am I missing ?

Edit :

I managed to edit the Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets to remove the line 262.

The second error is gone but the first error is still there. 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : Access is denied

Line 149 of Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets is :

```
 <Publish
      RuntimeToolingDirectory ="$(SDKToolingDirectory)"
      ProjectFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
      Project="$(KPackWorkingDirectory)"
      Runtime="$(FinalPublishVersion)"
      WwwRoot="$(WebRoot)"
      WwwRootOut="$(WwwRootOut)"
      NoSource="$(NoSourceFlag)"
      Quiet="$(QuietFlag)"
      IncludeSymbols ="$(IncludeSymbolsFlag)"
      Native ="$(NativeFlag)"
      Configuration="$(PublishConfiguration)"
      Out="$(PublishOutputPathNoTrailingSlash)"
      ExternalToolsPath="$(ExternalToolsPath)"
      IsFilePreview="$(FilePreview)" 
      IISCommand="$(IISCommand)"
      SDKToolingIdentifier="$(SDKToolingIdentifier)"
      PublishFramework="$(PublishFramework)"
      PublishRuntime="$(PublishRuntime)"
      NoBuild="$(NoBuildFlag)"
      BuildOutDirectory ="$(BuildOutDirNoSlash)" 
      EnvironmentVariables="@(DnuPublishEnvironmentVariables)"/>
```

Comment: Try to open VS2015 with Run as administrator option, my friend.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't solve it. I always open my solution on as administrator. Just to be sure I opened VS 2015 in administrator, then opened the solution ... to the same error.

Comment: Hi my friend. You can try creating a new profile and publish again.

Comment: I tried to create a new publish profile, and got the same error.

I managed to edit the Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets to remove the line 262. The error is gone but the first error is still there.
But now i have a better description then 'Access denied'

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : Access is denied

Comment: Guys, if you'll have found a solution, please do share :)